# Get a value with Jquery in a Thymeleaf Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I need to get value of ${job} inside the js but i dont know how. There is a variable that i can reach with using ${job.jobId} but i dont want to print it so i didnt write it into HTML

```js
$("#apply").click(function(e) {
  debugger
  var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
  var jobId = $row.find('${job.jobId}');
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location.href = "/admin";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Job">
  <tr id="jobs" th:each="job : ${job}">

    <div class="col-md-3" id="JobTitle">
      <span class="label label-default">Job Title</span>
      <td th:text="${job.jobTitle}" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" id="jobDescription">
      <span class="label label-primary">Job Description</span>
      <td th:text="${job.jobDescription}" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" id="numberOfPersonToHire">
      <span class="label label-success">Number Of Candidates</span>
      <td th:text="${job.numberOfPersonToHire}" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2" id="lastApplicationDate">
      <span class="label label-info">Last Date</span>
      <td th:text="${job.lastApplicationDate}" />
    </div>

    <button id="apply" type="button" class="btn btn-xs" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <img th:src="@{/images/apply.png}" height="20" width="auto"/> Apply
                </button>
    <hr />
  </tr>
</div>
```

## HTML

In addition: I'm working on Java Spring and this is thymeleaf html page

https://paste.ee/p/W1nrN

Comment: Could you show us the actual HTML output of the template. Also note that from the context I'm guessing that the HTML will be invalid, as `tr` elements can only be inside a `tbody`, and `td` must be within a `tr`. Neither can be children of `div` elements as in your example

Comment: I dont understand, do you want screen shot ?

Comment: No, you can just copy+paste it from the View Source window of your browser

Comment: If not from the source, then from the current state of the HTML DOM in your debugging tools.  The point is, you're using some kind of template system to *generate* additional HTML.  The jQuery code is going to operate on that resulting HTML, not on what you're showing in the question.

Comment: is `.val()` the function you are looking for? http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: even if this worked as-is, your row doesn't actually contain the ID anyway at the moment. I'd suggest making the ID a data-attribute of the row element.

Comment: Should i put it inside html but make it invisible? I have already reached that id inside the admin panel but this panel will be seen by normal users so i thought that users shouldnt have to see id. I can put it inside the html as i said but it will be invisible. Is that correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: that's what putting it as a `data-` attribute of the `<tr>` would do, yes. Then it won't be immediately visible to users (although if they did a View Source on the page, or used the Developer tools, then obviously it would).

Answer (score 2):

You can see the values ​​of all the variables that are available to thymeleaf, but you can only see them when making the request to the server.

Therefore you must do it using this code in your Script Tag:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    // ... you code here       
</script>
```

and then pass the value of the variable in this way, here are 2 examples:

```
var proyect=[[${proyect.name}]];
```

or

```
var email = [(${user.email})];
```

if your IDE mark as error/warning you can do this:

```
var addr= "[(${address.street})]";
$('#street').val(addr);
```

You can also see a broader explanation here:
https://attacomsian.com/blog/thymeleaf-set-javascript-variable

Answer (score 0):

in the javascript get your job variable using the following code

```
var jsJob = [[${job}]];
```

Let me know if this worked for you